# C2065 undeclared identifier while assigning a define to an int

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

I have a small problem with a define. I want to assign it to an integer variable but the compiler says it's undeclared.

Here's what the code looks like:
defines.h

```
#ifndef DEFINES_H
#define DEFINES_H

#define MYDEFINE 2

#endif
```

myclass.h

```
namespace mynamespace {
class myClass {
    int someFunction();
};
}
```

myclass.cxx

```
#include "defines.h"
#include "myclass.h"
namespace mynamespace {
int myClass::someFunction() {
    int var = MYDEFINE;
    return 0;
}
}
```

In the line with the int assignment the compiler error takes place. I also tried to use another define, defined in the same header file as above, as a function parameter with the same effect. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

I know using defines is a bad habit, but I only extend an existing project and I try to stay in their design ways.

EDIT: The error message simply is: `Fehler  1   error C2065: 'MYDEFINE': nichtdeklarierter Bezeichner   ...` As you might see this is not the real source code, but I think I was very careful while putting together the question.

EDIT2: Thanks for the hint with the #warning. There were 2 files with the same name in different folders. I've no idea why the compiler didn't bring this up. Anyway, it works now.

Comment: Please include the exact error message you're getting, sometimes the devil is in the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check whether the symbol MYDEFINE is really defined.

Check whether the header file where
    it is declared is really included
    (and compiled). Use #warning near the define to make sure it is compiled for myclass.cxx:

```
#ifndef DEFINES_H
#define DEFINES_H

#define MYDEFINE 2
#warning My define is defined

#endif
```

If it is not compiling (you'll not find the warning message in compilation log), make a search for DEFINES_H. It might be already defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put it all together:

```
    #ifndef DEFINES_H
    #define DEFINES_H
    #define MYDEFINE 2
    #endif

    namespace mynamespace {
    class myClass {
        int someFunction();
    };    // note ; missing in your code
    }

    namespace mynamespace {
    int myClass::someFunction() {
        int var = MYDEFINE;
        return 0;
    }
```

This compiles with no errors, so there is something wrong in your #includes.

Comment: +1 Nice catch. Little syntax errors usually give the compiler a lot of grief and this is a classic one.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I forgot the ; and also to #include "myclass.h".

Answer (score 1):

It's probably complaining about you not having declared your class. Try #including "myclass.h"

Edit:

Oh, missing ';' after your class declaration.

Comment: heh heh, oh well. I shouldn't be so literal with example code, i suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Some other header file also uses DEFINES_H?

One argument for #pragma once...

Comment: That tends to make no difference, as you still run into problems with two "defines.h" headers in a project.

Comment: I would add that #pragma once Microsoft specific, not standard.

Comment: #pragma once is not just MS, e.g. gcc also implements it.  It is not recognized by all preprocessors though so if you're in a really diverse environment it won't be usable.

Comment: @MSalters Not so (although other compilers may be broken) - I just tried this with 2 header files with same name in different paths: both get processed, whereas with #ifdef guards they don't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see what the preprocessor is doing to your code - try compiling myclass.cxx with the -P flag and examining the .i file so generated.